# C# Regex returning false, but it looks like it should be true. Two digits, one or two alpha, then six digits

Tags: c#, regex

My code is comparing a Regex pattern to a string value, and in my opinion it looks like it is a match.  However the result is always false.  I'm not seeing where my error is. Here are some lines of code:

```
            string pattern = @"d{2}\[a-zA-Z]{1,2}\d{6}";

            Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
            bool match = regex.IsMatch(value.ToString());
```

match is always = false. value.ToString is = "11D123456" which seems to me should match 2 digits, followed by 1 or 2 letters, followed by 6 digits.

If anyone can explain why it is not a successful match, that would be greatly appreciated.

[image: value.ToString()]

Comment: You forgot ``\`` before `d` and used a redundant ``\`` before `[`. `@"\d{2}[a-zA-Z]{1,2}\d{6}";`, or even `@"^\d{2}[a-zA-Z]{1,2}\d{6}$";`. I suggest removing the post since these look like typos to me.

Comment: \d{2}[a-zA-Z]{1,2}\d{6}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your pattern from

`d{2}\[a-zA-Z]{1,2}\d{6}`

To

`\d{2}[a-zA-Z]{1,2}\d{6}`

You were treating both `[` and `d` as literal characters.

Comment: Bingo. Thanks for the help. I knew that I was dealing with some type of syntax issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change to this **\d{2}[a-zA-Z]{1,2}\d{6}**.
Your initial regex is interpreted as
[image]

You need to change to **\d{2}[a-zA-Z]{1,2}\d{6}** ,which can be interpreted as
[image]

PD: I strongly recommend that you use Expresso. It's a free tool that help you learning and testing regex.
http://www.ultrapico.com/expresso.htm

Comment: Or even regex101.com, which has a code generator for some languages (and others are compatible at least with the way the generator escapes strings)

Answer (score 0):

using the debugger you will see that this will return true

```
string pattern = @"\d{2}[a-zA-Z]{1,2}\d{6}";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
bool match = regex.IsMatch(value.ToString());
```

> this was incorrect d{2}[a-zA-Z]{1,2}\d{6}